# Create heirachy of post terms from array & assign post to terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, array

I have a text string called `$location_string` which is an address in this format: *1 Victoria Street, Wellington, New Zealand* as well as a custom hierarchical taxonomy called *location*.

I am trying to achieve the following:

1) Create *location* terms for each of the objects in the array. Country would be the top-level term, city a child of country, and street address a child of city.

2) Assign all the terms in the array to the post set by `$post_id`

I realise the code below is pretty flawed- any ideas on how I could fix it? Currently it only creates street and country, as well as creating street twice:

```
$location_array_reversed = array_reverse( $location_array );

$i = 0;
$len = count($location_array_reversed);

$location_array_ids = array();

foreach( $location_array_reversed as $term ){

    if ($i == 0) {

        // Top level term
        wp_insert_term( $term, 'location' );
        $tag = get_term_by( 'slug', $term, 'location' );
        $term_id =  $tag->term_id;

        // Save term ID to array
        $location_array_ids[] = $term_id;

    } else if ($i == $len - 1) {

        wp_insert_term( $term, 'location', array( 'parent'=> $term_id ) );

        // Child terms
        wp_insert_term( $term, 'location' );
        $tag = get_term_by( 'slug', $term, 'location' );
        $term_id =  $tag->term_id;

        // Save term ID to array
        $location_array_ids[] = $term_id;

    }

    $i++;

}

// Now assign terms to post
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $location_array_ids, 'location' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first and last term is added, all others are omitted in your code. A street is created twice, because you double-insert the last element of the array.

```
else if ($i == $len - 1) {
    wp_insert_term( $term, 'location', array( 'parent'=> $term_id ) );
    // Child terms
    wp_insert_term( $term, 'location' );
}
```

Try to change `foreach` loop:

```
$location_array_reversed = array_reverse( $location_array );

$parent_id = 0; 
$location_array_ids = [];
$taxonomy_slug = 'location';
foreach( $location_array_reversed as $term ) { 

    $res = term_exists( $term, $taxonomy_slug, $parent_id );
    if ( $res === NULL || $res == 0 )
        $res = wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy_slug, ['parent' => $parent_id] );

    $term_id =  (int) $res['term_id'];  // ID of existing or inserted term

    // Save term ID to array 
    $location_array_ids[] = $term_id; 
    $parent_id = $term_id; 
}
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $location_array_ids, $taxonomy_slug);
```

[`wp_insert_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) returns ID of the inserted term, so you don't need to use `get_term_by()` to get ID of the inserted element.

Comment: Hmm, that works if the location doesn't exist, but errors out if it already does. I tried checking if the post exists but this results in no terms being assigned:

`$parent_id = 0;

foreach( $location_array_reversed as $term ) {

 if( $term !== 0 && $term !== null ) {

  $res = get_term_by('name', $term, 'location');

 } else {

     $res = wp_insert_term( $term, 'location', ['parent' => $parent_id] );
     
    }

    $term_id =  $res['term_id'];  // last inserted term

    // Save term ID to array
    $location_array_ids[] = $term_id;
    $parent_id = $term_id;

}`

Comment: @warm__tape I updated the code